# malformed array literal error working with postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to create and populate a table to store some data, but when i try to populate it i receive the error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "znz"
LINE 30: values ('znz','costanzino@gmail.com',  01-01-1990,'costanzo'...
                 ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 990
```

this is my code:

```
create table Employee (
CF                  char[3] primary key,
email               varchar[100]    unique      not null,
date_of_birth       date                        not null,
employee_name       varchar[20]                 not null,
employee_surname    varchar[20]                 not null,
sex                 char    check(sex = 'M' or sex ='F' or sex = 'A')   default 'A',
city                varchar[20]                 not null,
street              varchar[50]                 not null,
e_number            varchar[5]                  not null,
CAP                 char[5]                                             default null,
country             char (2)                    not null                default 'it',
salary              numeric(9,2)                not null                default 0,
telephone_number    varchar[13]);
```

```
insert into Employee(CF,email,date_of_birth,employee_name,employee_surname,sex,city,street,e_number,CAP,country,salary,telephone_number) 
values ('znz','costanzino@gmail.com',       01-01-1990,'costanzo','vecchio','M',        'Padova','Roma','2B','35020','IT',      2000,   '+398887760093');
```

this is just the first piece of a bigger project, and i receive the same error everytime i try to insert a value.
I'm working with pgAdmin4 version 6.2

Comment: I think you want to use parentheses to specify the column size, not brackets. i.e. `char(3)` rather than `char[3]`. PostgreSQL supports array columns and that's what `char[]` means.

Comment: put the date in single quotes

Comment: One of your columns is an array. Add {} around the column. So for example INSERT INTO "Employee" (yourarraycolumn) VALUES ('{value}')

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: Thanks @mu is too short, it worked perfectly